# Are there other variations of "slow and steady wins the race"?

Tags: idioms, variants

We know the hare and tortoise story but are there other variants of "slow and steady wins the race"?

Comment: I'm closevoting as Not Constructive, because this is an "invitation to submit lists". But I can't let my personal favourite [Softly, Softly, Catchee Monkey](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Softly%2C%20Softly%2C%20Catchee%20Monkey) be missed out.

Comment: Or how about "The journey of a thousand miles begins with the first step" (followed by another step, and another, and another, and another, and another . . ..

Comment: How is the question ambiguous when someone gave a pretty good answer?

Comment: @2er0 For many, it just means "I don't know the answer." :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*The Facts on File Dictionary of Proverbs* (1983) suggests these, under the heading "Perseverance":

> Perseverance kills the game.
>
> It's dogged as does it.
>
> The tortoise wins the race while the hare is sleeping.
>
> The race is not to the swift, nor the battle to the strong.

Linda & Roger Flavell, *Dictionary of Proverbs and Their Origins* (1993) adds this one:

> Little strokes fell great oaks.

On the somewhat related subject of patience yoked to perseverance (that is, of not trying to do too much all at once), we have these options:

> Rome wasn't built in a day.
>
> More haste, less speed.